# ActiveQuery count() and all() return different results

Tags: php, yii2

I have a query:

```
$query = Products::find();
$query->joinWith('vendor', true, 'LEFT JOIN');
$query->joinWith('values', true,'LEFT JOIN');
$query->where(['<>', 'stock', 7]);
$query->andWhere(['category_id' => $model->id]);

if (!empty($activeVendors))
    $query->andWhere(['lan_vendors.id' => array_flip($activeVendors)]);

if (!empty($activeValues)){
    $query->andWhere(['lan_products_values.value_id' => $activeValues]);
}

$totalProducts = $query->count();
$products = $query->all();
```

In result:

```
$totalProducts = 12;
count($products) = 3;
```

I can not solve this problem. Reading the documentation did not help. Is there something wrong with the database itself?

Comment: how you obtain  $products?? .. is not clear ..

Comment: try to dump `$totalProducts` and `$products`

Comment: @Bara'ayyash in dump  `$totalProducts = string(2) "12"` and `$products` is array(3) of `app\models\Products Object `

Comment: @scaisEdge 
I need to receive goods corresponding to certain characteristics and certain brands. This is part of the work of filters for products in the online store

Comment: Use yii2 debug toolbar (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-debug-index.html) or logging with profile level (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html) to check what actual queries was executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your left join statements generate duplicate rows.
after a the query runs yii [removes duplicate data](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/ActiveQuery.php#L237) and creates a usable array of uniqe `Product` models

the duplicate rows are not avoidable in your case since you enforce eager loading with left join

```
$query->joinWith('vendor', true, 'LEFT JOIN');
$query->joinWith('values', true,'LEFT JOIN');
```

you can try to run something like this to adjust the relations to your conditions, and follow the generated queries 
in the debug log,

```
$query->with([
    'vendor' => function (\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) use ($activeVendors) {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['lan_vendors.id' => array_flip($activeVendors)]);
    },
    'values' => function (\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) use ($activeValues) {
        $query->andWhere(['lan_products_values.value_id' => $activeValues]);
    },
])
```

also follow the generated queries in the debug log, it's a usefull way of figuring out what happens in the two cases

Comment: Thank you. You marked the problem and I understood why this happens. And I solved my problem as follows: `$ totalProducts = $ query-> count ('DISTINCT lan_products.id');`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are joining additional tables here most probably you have got dupicated results - you can check it by running this query manually outside of Yii.

Query `count()` is showing you all the rows fetched from database (with duplicates).

`all()` on the other hand takes the fetched rows and while populating the Yii 2 models it [removes duplicates](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.12/framework/db/ActiveQuery.php#L211) so you have got unique ones.